# getTimeInMillis() returns different values for same dates

Tags: java, date, datetime, calendar, timestamp

I think I'm not understanding `getTimeInMillis()` properly. I've always thought that a milliseconds timestamp represents one date, but on my case, it made me think different. Here, I'm using a method to add a timestamp to an array, like so:

```
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
date.set(2015, 9, 25, 12, 0);
timeArray.push(date.getTimeInMillis());
```

On some other part of the code, I am doing the same with the same date:

```
Calendar date2 = Calendar.getInstance();
date2.set(2015, 9, 25, 12, 0);
```

Unfortunately, this comparison returns false:

```
timeArray.get(0) == date2.getTimeInMillis();
```

Shouldn't those two values be true? Or maybe I've understood the `getTimeInMillis()` method wrong? If so, how can I achieve what I am trying to do in some other way?

Comment: What's `timeArray`?  Have you tried using `.equals` instead?

Comment: @MadProgrammer `timeArray` is an `ArrayList` of `long` type, and I think I'm doing the comparison correctly. The problem is that when I iterate through the array items, I can see the milliseconds are different for the same dates.

Comment: Ah, you know what the problem is more likely to be, `Calendar.set(int, int, int, int, int);` doesn't change the second or millisecond values, *"Previous values of other fields are retained.  If this is not desired, call clear() first"*

Comment: @MadProgrammer Since the answer I was seeking lives on your comment, if you'd like, make it an actual answer so I can choose it as correct.

Comment: It's okay, Timofey answered with pretty much everything I was going to say ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks a lot both of you then!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's take a look at [documenation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)).
So according to documenation to the `set` method:

> Sets the values for the calendar fields YEAR, MONTH, DAY_OF_MONTH,
>   HOUR_OF_DAY, and MINUTE. **Previous values of other fields are retained**.
>   If this is not desired, call clear() first.

So the fix should be simple: just call `clear()` method first.

Comment: *Previous values of other fields are retained*. But in OP's case `date2` is a new object... its time had never been set before.

OP's issue seems to be that the seconds/milliseconds were never specified in OP's snippet, so they are left undefined. The reason `clear` happens to work is a side effect of clear setting values of all time fields to `0` (on my system anyway), so the second/milliseconds aren't then undefined. But setting them to 0 isn't documented behaviour for `clear`, as its docs say *sets all the calendar field values and the time value of this Calendar undefined*.

Answer (score 0):

## Immutable Objects

The [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33336229/642706) by [Timofey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5165589/timofey) is correct. This demonstrates the problems that come with the old date-time classes being highly mutable. In contrast, the alternatives, [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) and [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), both use [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). In this pattern, fresh new objects are instantiated based on the original object rather than mutating the original.

## java.time

Here is some example code in java.time as of Java 8. An [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is a moment on the timeline in UTC while [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) is an Instant adjusted into a time zone ([`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)).

Build a `ZonedDateTime` piece by piece: [date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), [time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html), zone.

```
LocalDate datePortion = LocalDate.of ( 2015 , 9 , 25 );
LocalTime timePortion = LocalTime.NOON;
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of ( datePortion , timePortion , zoneId );
```

Extract the milliseconds-from-epoch by first accessing the `Instant` inside the `ZonedDateTime`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant ();
long millisecondsSinceEpoch = instant.toEpochMilli ();  // WARNING: Data loss. The java.time types have nanosecond resolution.
```

Going the other direction. **BEWARE:** This involves possible data-loss. The java.time framework uses a resolution of [nanoseconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond), 9 digits of fractional second. [Milliseconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) is only 3 digits of fractional second.

```
Instant instantFromMillis = Instant.ofEpochMilli ( millisecondsSinceEpoch );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "Date: " + datePortion + " Time: " + timePortion + " in zoneId: " + zoneId + " is " + zdt + " with milliseconds since epoch: " + millisecondsSinceEpoch );
```

When run.

> Date: 2015-09-25 Time: 12:00 in zoneId: America/Montreal is 2015-09-25T12:00-04:00[America/Montreal] with milliseconds since epoch: 1443196800000